# Transfer/ Merge this account with my Launchpad account

Tags: discussion, login, launchpad

The account I'm logged in with now is one that I guess was made when I logged in for the first time. It uses my Gmail account to authenticate it. But I am working very hard to try and move entirely away from everything Google. I have an Android phone, but don't use the Play store at all. Instead I use F-Droid Repository. And later if the 100% free software rom, Replicant, is ported to a Verizon device. I will switch to using it.

But upon trying to switch AskUbuntu over to my Launchpad ID clem11388 instead of Gmail. It instead created an entirely new user called: user65492 . All my points/repuation are back to zero with that account. And I very much don't feel like starting from scratch. Is there anyway I can have a moderator transfer this account over to my Launchpad ID? I can provide login credentials (only by secure means) if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I have merged your [launchpad ID](https://askubuntu.com/users/65492/user65492) account with your *Daniel Clem* account.  You should now be able to login using your Launchpad account credentials.